# How to enqueue JavaScript for specific WordPress pages only?

Tags: functions, javascript, wp-enqueue-script

I'm new to WordPress, tried first searching for this and found a few related answers, none of which i fully understood. Will appreciate a few lines of concrete instructions. 
I have a WordPress page that has a script with a few functions and then another short script that uses them. I'd like to reuse these functions in some other pages. so:

- do I create a separate js file? where do I put it? in wp-includes/js ?
- how do i expose them to pages (do i put in functions.php, via the
  register and enque? how do I specify the path exactly? or is there
  another way to do this?
- Is there a way not to expose to all pages, but rather to specific 
  few ones?
- In the using pages, how do I load and call these functions?

below is the structure of code I have now.
Thanks!
Yoav

```
<script> 
// an example for the  functions i want to reuse function
foo(x,y) { 
    ... 
    do stuff 
    return z; 
} 
function goo() { 
// <![CDATA[ ..
     do stuff ... 
 // ]]> 
} 
</script> 

<script> 
// an example for the  real
page val x = "something"; 
val y = "other"; 
var message = foo(x, y);

// this will add some  content to the page goo(); 
// this adds some more 
document.write(message); 
</script>
```

Answer (score 10):

Yes, create a separate JS file and store it in your plugin or theme folder, lets call it `example.js`. This file should contain all the common function you need to execute in multiple pages, page-specific functions should go to a separate file.

After you've written your code in the `example.js` you need to include it on WordPress, to do this you need to use this function

```
function my_scripts() {
    // Page ID, title, slug, or array of such.
    // e.g. is_page('My page title') - page title
    // e.g. is_page(2) - page id 
    // e.g. is_page('my-page-title') - page slug
    // e.g. is_page( array( 'page1', 'page1')) - in this example an array of page slugs.
    // Check out the references for more on this function.
    if ( is_page( array( 'about-us', 'contact', 'management' ) ) {
        wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', 'path/to/example.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
    }
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'my_scripts' );
```

You can put this function in `functions.php`. If the file is in your theme directory then use this

```
wp_enqueue_script( 'script-name', get_template_directory_uri() . '/example.js', array(), '1.0.0', true );
```

#### Tip:

If the `example.js` is in your plugin folder then you need to use
`plugin_dir_url( __FILE__ )` instead of `get_template_directory_uri()` where `__FILE__` is a PHP constant for current file path.

To set a variable and use its value across different pages in your JS file, you need this function.

```
wp_localize_script('script-name', 'array_name', array(
        'variable_name' => 'Variable value'
    )
);
```

#### Note:

`wp_localize_script` MUST be called after the script has been registered using `wp_register_script()` or `wp_enqueue_script()`.

#### References:

- [wp_enqueue_script()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_enqueue_script/) - Used to actually enqueue the script
- [wp_localize_script()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_localize_script) - Used to pass any variables/data from WordPress/PHP to JS
- [get_template_directory_uri()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_template_directory_uri/) - Retrieve theme directory URI.
- [is_page()](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/is_page/) - Condition to check if you want to load the JS on specific pages only.
- [plugin_dir_url()](https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/plugin_dir_url) - Get URL for the plugin directory.
- [__FILE__](http://php.net/manual/en/language.constants.predefined.php)  - PHP constant

Comment: I have voted to reject your edit since the change you made in the title changes the meaning of the question itself.

Comment: @Mark Kaplun, What about the the formatting in the content? Will that be rejected too? It took some time on mobile.

Comment: it might still be accepted in any case ;) two votes are needed to accept or reject. It is possible to edit your edit, but I am not sure who will get the credit after that and didn't want to do it, wasn;t sure if you would have like someone doing it ;)

Comment: I'm grateful for the answer, but it didn't work for me. The script and its function were not reached. Still investigating why.

Comment: I tried that on my local install and it works fine, I use the same functions on my plugins. Check out the references I provided. This however, requires knowledge of PHP and a little bit WordPress.

Comment: All you need is a simple `IF` condition to check for required page before you enqueue your script. Are you creating the JS file in correct directory, is the directory path specified in the `wp_enqueue_script` correct?

Comment: @YoavOssia, are you still not able to solve this problem?

Comment: I went to a simpler solution . I just included the script in the few WordPress pages that use it. (<script> src=... </script>) and used the functions directly. Seems simpler and saves my the if (...) in PHP. Is there any downside with this approach?

Comment: I would still suggest you to use the method I described as this will help you maintain better code and it will be easier for you to update your JS files, this will also help you if you want to add the JS file to a few more pages in the future it will be as easy as adding there slug-name or ID.

Comment: But once I know I want these functions from a page, it's way simpler to simple add this one liner of include then going to the PHP and add there....  Maybe because I come from traditional programming, and this resembles the c# and C++ style I'm used to....   But is there any technical flaw with this approach? can it break?